# Batch file create folder in server

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

how can i create a folder in a server according to the computer's username and upload files to it using ftp.
I am currently using this code:

```
ftp -s:script.dat server-ip
```

and this in script.dat

```
username
password
ascii
cd public_html
put data\1.txt
put data\2.txt
put data\3.txt
put data\4.txt
put data\5.txt
put data\6.txt
close
quit
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server other than through FTP? What kind of server is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
(   
echo username
echo password
echo ascii
echo cd public_html
echo cd data
echo mkdir %username%
echo cd %username%
echo mput *.txt
echo close
echo quit
)>script.dat
```

Comment: I suppose it would help if I included the echo's ;)

Comment: this is only going to create a script.dat with the currently logged in users folder. If you want all of your users names created, I'll need to know what type of network and OS you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much, I noticed that I should include the echos.

Comment: A username can contain spaces - What will FTP do with spaces in the username?